# Encrypted streams in C# are shrinking

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, stream, rijndael

I am obviously doing something wrong here, but I don't understand why this is happening. I have been experianceing bugs in my encrypt stream function and added additional code to display to Visual studio's debugger what is going on in the function. To my discovery, the encrypted version of what ever data I send into it is shorter than the original stream, and attempts to decrypt the stream results in an even shorter stream.

```
        public Stream encryptStream(Stream input)
    {
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        RijndaelManaged alg = new RijndaelManaged();
        alg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        byte[] key = HashStringMD5(DefaultKey);
        alg.KeySize = key.Length * 8;
        alg.Key = key;
        alg.IV = key;


        CryptoStream crypt = new CryptoStream(output, alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);



        output.Position = 0;
        input.CopyTo(crypt);
        byte[] EncryptedCopy = output.ToArray();
        byte[] InputCopy = new byte[input.Length];
        input.Position = 0;
        input.Read(InputCopy, 0, InputCopy.Length);
        output.Position = 0;
        MemoryStream test = new MemoryStream();
        crypt.Close();
        crypt = new CryptoStream(test, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        crypt.Write(EncryptedCopy, 0, EncryptedCopy.Length);
        test.Position = 0;
        byte[] DecryptionTest = test.ToArray();


        input.Position = 0;


        return output;
    }
```

not sure what is causing the data loss as shown below [image]

Comment: You're only closing `crypt` *after* you've copied the data out of `output`. Try closing it straight after you've called `input.CopyTo(crypt)` instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to flush to the containing stream at the right time. Also, you have quite a few resources which implement `IDisposable` and are disposed of most easily by employing the `using` construct. This should produce the results you are looking for as well as properly deterministically disposing of resources:

```
public Stream encryptStream(Stream input)
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();

    using (var alg = new RijndaelManaged { Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 })
    {
        var key = HashStringMD5(DefaultKey);
        alg.KeySize = key.Length * 8;
        alg.Key = key;
        alg.IV = key;
        byte[] encryptedCopy;

        using (var enc = alg.CreateEncryptor())
        {
            var crypt = new CryptoStream(output, enc, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            input.CopyTo(crypt);
            crypt.FlushFinalBlock();
            encryptedCopy = output.ToArray();
        }

        var inputCopy = new byte[input.Length];

        input.Position = 0;
        input.Read(inputCopy, 0, inputCopy.Length);
        using (var test = new MemoryStream())
        using (var dec = alg.CreateDecryptor())
        using (var crypt = new CryptoStream(test, dec, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            crypt.Write(encryptedCopy, 0, encryptedCopy.Length);
            crypt.FlushFinalBlock();

            var decryptionTest = test.ToArray();

            if (decryptionTest.Length != inputCopy.Length || decryptionTest.Where((t, i) => t != inputCopy[i]).Any())
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("not orthogonal");
            }
        }
    }

    input.Position = 0;
    output.Position = 0;
    return output;
}
```

Though I might split the testing code into a separate method as it adds noise to the simplicity of the encrypting code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I had no clue that I needed to flush the streams, which explains why I was losing the last block. Also, I had no clue I could use the using keyword like that. You learn something new every day, as the old saying goes.